# Validate User Inputed Phrases Java

Tags: java, validation, input, phrase

Trying to build a program (Java) in which the user types in their size (E.g Large, Small, L or S),
This then relays their size back to them using a sout saying "You Selected Size: Small" (eg System.out.println("You Selected Size: " + selectedSize)

Just wondering if theres a way that i can make it so it validates the input, so it would only accept the phrases "small" "large" "L" and "S"

I can find help with validators that work for int but can't find one for words/phrases without it being very specific to the question

```
import java.util.Scanner;

{
    System.out.print("Enter Size:  ");

    Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);

    String selectedsize = size.next();

    if (size.hasNext());
    {
    System.out.println("Size Selected is: " + name1);
    }
}
```

}

Probably pretty basic for a lot of you but thanks for any advice!

Comment: tried hasNext as shown above but i can only get that to work with Ints

Comment: it's `nextLine` for string input. It'll wait for the user to hit enter then read the line.

Answer (score 0):

For a console app I think the easiest way would be to just check if the user typed the correct size, and loop if not.

Maybe:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    String input = in.nextLine();
    switch(input.toLowerCase()) {
        case "small":
        case "s":
            chooseSmall();
            break;
        case "large":
        case "l":
            chooseLarge();
            break;
        case "q":
            System.out.println("Good bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        default:
            System.out.println("Incorrect option. Please try again.");
            continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

warning: untested. Needs Java 7 for string in switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the keyword `switch`.

It can replace the `if ()`, also have a close look at the end of the `if ()` line... there is some 'strange' character there.

Also the if should be done over the variable `selectedsize`...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter Size:  ");

    Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);

    String selectedsize = "";

    if (size.hasNext()) {
        selectedsize = size.next();
    }

    switch (selectedsize) {
    case "small":
    case "s":
        System.out.println("Size Selected is: " + selectedsize);
        break;
    case "large":
    case "l":
        System.out.println("Size Selected is: " + selectedsize);
        break;          
    default:
        System.out.println("exit");
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `ArrayList` to do something similar to the solutions using `switch`. Anything you add to this `ArrayList` will be an accepted response.

```
//Set up accepted responses
ArrayList<String> acceptedResponses = new ArrayList<>();
acceptedResponses.add("LARGE");
acceptedResponses.add("L");
acceptedResponses.add("SMALL");
acceptedResponses.add("S");

System.out.print("Enter Size:  ");
Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
String selectedsize = size.next();
if (acceptedResponses.contains(selectedsize.toUpperCase())){
    System.out.println("Size Selected is: " + selectedsize);
}else{
    System.out.println("Not a valid shirt size");
}
```

Hope this helps.